# BETWEEN Clause returning wrong result

Tags: postgresql

When i try

```
select "leads".* 
from "leads" 
where ("leads"."completed" in (true)) and ("leads"."status" in ('active')) 
and (
    leads.created_at between COALESCE('2021-12-01 03:00:00.000'::timestamptz, '-infinity') and COALESCE('2021-12-02 03:59:59.999'::timestamptz, 'infinity')
) order by
    GREATEST(leads.created_at, leads.requalified_at) DESC
, "leads"."id" asc limit 41;
```

It doesn`t return anything

But

```
leads.created_at >= COALESCE('2021-12-01 03:00:00.000'::timestamptz, '-infinity')
```

works perfectly. I was expecting with the between clause to return a result in between 2 dates, which did not happen. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `COALESCE('2021-12-01 03:00:00.000'::timestamptz, '-infinity')` does not make any sense as it will never resolve to `'-infinity'`.   In the actual query are using a field value?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes, it is using a field value, a dynamic variable coming from frontend which can resolve into NULL, which i fallback into -infinity to get a broader range

Comment: Then you need to find what values are actually ending up in the query. Right now a value that is not `NULL` but does not fit your `BETWEEN` assumption would cause no results to be returned e.g. am `AND` that is less then `BETWEEN`. You can log from the front end or crank up the logging in the Postgresq log to see what is actually hitting the database.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver this query i had manually written on my console and tried it, it does not work. This is the data coming to it!

Comment: if i remove the coalesce, with this data, it does not work either, so the problem is not on the infinity

Comment: As I said `COALESCE('2021-12-01 03:00:00.000'::timestamptz, '-infinity')` is not going to resolve to `-infinity` or `infinity` as the first value is a non-NULL value.  From you said about `leads.created_at >= COALESCE('2021-12-01 03:00:00.000'::timestamptz, '-infinity')` I have to conclude their are  no rows that have `leads.created_at` falling between `'2021-12-01 03:00:00.000'` and `'2021-12-02 03:59:59.999'`. In other words they are only greater then `'2021-12-02 03:59:59.999'`

Comment: Look at what you get when you do `>= COALESCE('2021-12-01 03:00:00.000'::timestamptz, '-infinity')`. I'm betting there are no  `leads.created_at` that fall in your `BETWEEN` range.

Comment: Works for me.  It seems like you have no values which are between those two times, so there is nothing for you to find.

Comment: replace `leads.created_at between COALESCE('2021-12-01 03:00:00.000'::timestamptz, '-infinity') and COALESCE('2021-12-02 03:59:59.999'::timestamptz, 'infinity')` by `leads.created_at <@ tstzrange(your_front_end_start_parameter, your_front_end_end_parameter)` which will handle the NULL values properly